# Adding fontAwesome to Primary Menu returns <i></i> after saving the menu

Tags: plugins, menus, fonts

Tried all possible alternatives to have the fontawesome icons displaying in the menu but can't figure out why isn't working!

- trying deactivate all plugins and still doing the same
- tried switching theme and still doing the same
- cleared browser cache
- used CDN instead fontawesome plugin

So what happen is that when trying to place `<i class="fa-solid fa-bolt-lightning"></i>` and saving, only the i tag is left... without the class `<i></i>`

Also trying with switching the " to ' like `<i class='fa-solid fa-bolt-lightning'></i>` or adding the title

The result is always the same `<i></i>`

Tried the [] approach with `[icon name="bolt-lightning" prefix="fas"]` and it renders as it is [image: [icon name="bolt-lightning" prefix="fas"]]

Any other alternative approach I could try?